# Error using pip commands after 19.0.1 update

Tags: python, pip, package

I just updated pip and some packages and now I get the following error when running just about any command like `show` or `list` (`-V` works):

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2897, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2888, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 176, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/show.py", line 47, in run
    results, list_files=options.files, verbose=options.verbose):
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/show.py", line 137, in print_results
    pkg.project_name for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/show.py", line 138, in <listcomp>
    if name in [required.name for required in pkg.requires()]
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2635, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2899, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2908, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2890, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1410, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1522, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/sterlingbutters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/-ytz-2018.5.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Is this just my configuration or is there a known bug, etc?

Any ideas on how to fix it? - I can't say I've ever had this problem before

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall anaconda?

Comment: No, I just stumbled on the issue. What makes you think its Anaconda if all I did was update pip?

Comment: Found this open issue: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6194